# How to configure ADF git with specyfic commit hash

Tags: azure, github, command-line-interface, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory configured with GitHub. My problem is that after integrating with GitHub using the *az cli* command:

```
az datafactory configure-factory-repo --location="East US"
--factory-resource-id "/subscriptions/********-****-****-****-***********/resourceGroups/adf-stack/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf_factory"
--factory-git-hub-configuration account-name="githubName" collaboration-branch="main" repository-name="adf" root-folder="/dafactory"
```

In the GUI, I can only see the latest version of the repository, not the older versions.

For example, I create one linked service, then publish the changes. Then I create a second linked service and publish the changes again. Now I have two linked services, but I would like to go back to the state when there was only one.

I execute:

```
az datafactory configure-factory-repo --location="East US"
--factory-resource-id "/subscriptions/********-****-****-****-***********/resourceGroups/adf-stack/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf_factory"
--factory-git-hub-configuration account-name="githubName" collaboration-branch="main" repository-name="adf" root-folder="/dafactory last-commit-id='1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'"
```

And in the GIT configuration, it shows that ADF is using that hash `(1234567890123456789012345678901234567890)`. Unfortunately, the two linked services are still visible.

Expect: Configure ADF GitHub repo to use a specific commit hash. The old version should be visible in GUI.

Comment: @Pravash Panigrahi, Are you trying to do a QFE [or a hotfix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-hotfix-environment) ?